# Write a DataFrame to multiple paths

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I would like to write a DataFrame to 4 differents paths `/A`, `/B`, `/C`, `/D` on AWS S3.

```py
def heavy_computation(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    ...

res: DataFrame = heavy_computation(df1, df2)

res.write.parquet("s3://bucket/path/to/A")
res.write.parquet("s3://bucket/path/to/B")
res.write.parquet("s3://bucket/path/to/C")
res.write.parquet("s3://bucket/path/to/D")
```

Because in practice, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are unrelated and don't necessarily represent partitions of my data, my snippets runs in about 4 times the duration necessary to write only a single path. To optimize the code, I was thinking of writing only once to `/A` and then running this Bash Script.

```bash
aws s3 sync --recursive s3://bucket/path/to/A s3://bucket/path/to/B
aws s3 sync --recursive s3://bucket/path/to/A s3://bucket/path/to/C
aws s3 sync --recursive s3://bucket/path/to/A s3://bucket/path/to/D
```

Is there a smarter way to do this with only Spark SQL functional API?

Comment: If you are working with Databricks then you can use ```dbutils``` copy command to copy the data to other locations.

Comment: I am working with EMR

Comment: Did you try caching res dataframe before saving it to s3?

Comment: can you provide a code sample I am not sure of the subtleties of `.persist()`